# problem with makefile , has some error which syas "no input files"

Tags: makefile

I have following makefile

```
# Set the compiler and flags
CC = gcc
C_VERSION = c90
C_FLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=$(C_VERSION)

# project name
PROJECT_NAME = openu-assembler

# folders
SRC_FOLDER = src
OBJ_FOLDER = obj
BIN_FOLDER = bin

# object files
SOURCE_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_FOLDER)/*.c)

# the executable file
EXECUTABLE = $(BIN_FOLDER)/$(PROJECT_NAME)

# run the project
run: $(EXECUTABLE)
    ./$(EXECUTABLE)

# compile and run
compile: clean $(EXECUTABLE)
    ./$(EXECUTABLE)

# create the executable file, all object files must be created first
$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCE_FILES:$(SRC_FOLDER)/%.c=$(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o)
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@

# for each source file, create an object file
$(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o: $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.c
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# clean the project
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_FOLDER)/*.o
    rm -f $(BIN_FOLDER)/$(PROJECT_NAME)
```

Problem is it tells me :
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c90  -o bin/openu-assembler
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:30: bin/openu-assembler] Error 1

I have 3 files bin src and obj
obj after "make" has files in it
the input files are in bin file

tried to understand why is it like that but couldnt

Comment: You forgot to define `OBJ`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 30 in the makefile, which is what the error tells you to look at.

```
$(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@
```

Here you use the variable `OBJ` but nowhere in your makefile did you set this variable, so it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the object list from the source list, using the [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function:

```
# object files
SOURCE_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_FOLDER)/*.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.c,$(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o, $(SOURCE_FILES))
```

But it would probably be wiser to go the other way: instead of telling Make to compile whatever it finds in the source folder, tell it what object files to build, and let it deduce the source files it needs. Among other advantages, it allows you to keep the sources of several executables in the same directory.